# Selenium (2.29.1) hover over under Firefox (18.01)

Tags: java, selenium, hover, selenium-webdriver

I have a page with a picture in it.
If i hover over the mouse a button appears in the top left corner. I want to use that button for couple of things (checking, clicking, etc).

I'm using this method for hover over:

> ```
>     Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) element;
>     Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();
>     mouse.mouseMove(hoverItem.getCoordinates());
> ```

This method perfectly working under IE (9) and Chrome (latest) but not under FireFox (18.01).
The script can't see that the button appeared therefore it can't be checked or pressed:

> Assert.assertTrue("Save button is missing!",
>   Browser.findElement(By.id("xxx")).isDisplayed());

I'm using 2.29.1 Selenium. Do you have any ideas what's wrong with the FireFox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a java 2.29.1 version anywhere..are you using java or .Net bindings?
The change log of 2.29 says firefox 18 support but doesnt mention native support.  That may be a reason.  Consider downgrading firefox to 17 since selenium 2.27 java version change log shows that support for native events has been added for 17.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium 2.29 doesnot support on firefox 18 because the latest version is not tested on FF18. It would work if you downgrade your firefox to version. Even I had problems with FF18 but works on FF17.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the using `Firefox` version is a Stable or Beta release. If Beta release change to a stable one. The most stable version was released on Jan 18 2013.

I too used Mouse Hover. But, i used different code.

**My code**

```
  //Assume you instantiate the driver instance properly anywhere else
  WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id(`IdName`));
  Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
  builder.moveToElement(elem).build().perform();
```

Try this code.

Comment: Hi. I created this method earlier but have the same result! Both methods are working on IE and Chrome, not working under FF. :(